# What's the step between writing a script in Python and opening the data it compiles in an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: python, excel, csv

Brand new to Python and programming for that matter so I feel like I'm missing a simple (or at least straight forward step). I'm learning how to build scripts with Python and found a nice tutorial article to get me started: http://www.gregreda.com/2013/03/03/web-scraping-101-with-python/

I can't seem to understand the step(s) that are needed to get from that script - to a workable CSV file where I can manipulate the data? Here's the example code I'm using:

```
__author__ = 'joshcrist'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

BASE_URL = "http://www.chicagoreader.com"

def get_category_links(section_url):
    html = urlopen(section_url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    boccat = soup.find("dl", "boccat")
    category_links = [BASE_URL + dd.a["href"] for dd in boccat.findAll("dd")]
    return category_links

def get_category_winner(category_url):
    html = urlopen(category_url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    category = soup.find("h1", "headline").string
    winner = [h2.string for h2 in soup.findAll("h2", "boc1")]
    runners_up = [h2.string for h2 in soup.findAll("h2", "boc2")]
    return {"category": category,
            "category_url": category_url,
            "winner": winner,
            "runners_up": runners_up}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `row=[1,2,3]; print ','.join(row);`

Comment: Which data do you want in csv format? What should the columns and rows be?